# file not found: HelloWorld.java

Tags: java, cmd, error-handling, file-not-found

I started to learn Java and the first task was do write a 'Hello World' Code.
Saved it in documents and had to open it in cmd.
thats what i type in:

```
cd documents
javac HelloWorld.java
```

my problem: I always get the error: file not found: HelloWorld.java

the class is definitely HelloWorld and its saved to as HelloWorld.java

but when I open this document the path says:

C:\Users\myusername\OneDrive\Documents\HelloWorld.java

hope you can understand my problem, thx for answers

Comment: You are saving it to OneDrive. Are you cd'ing to that or the local documents folder?

Comment: yes i think so, but in the documents the type is aswell java-file

Comment: how can i change that it always save to onedrive and if i cd to onedrive i dont know how to access to the documents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the java file is in your Documents folder, by writing:

```
dir
```

or for macos:

```
ls
```

But since you said it is in your OneDrive then you should navigate there with the `cd` command. (Use TAB to fill out the folder names and/or filenames for you automatically.
To check directory just write `cd` without anything behind it in windows, or `pwd` for macos.
When you've checked that the Java file is in your current directory you can just compile it normally with `javac`.

Comment: thank you for your help. the path was very hard to find because of the onedrive, do you know how to turn off OneDrive? I dont know why it always take the OneDrive path.

Comment: Hmm maybe your texteditor saves it automatically there? I don't really know why it would do that. But what I do before I start writing something is to create the file before writing, and not writing and then saving (hope you get what I mean). To do that in macos write "touch filename.java" and in Windows write "copy NUL filename.java". This works for every file type.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the change directory to your specific directory.

```
cd C:\Users\myusername\OneDrive\Documents\
javac HelloWorld.java
```

Comment: it haven´t worked in documents there always came an error with can´t find this path... i had to save it at the desktop now it works.